# string is not returning correct reverse string in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, array-algorithms

I am trying to reverse the string using following function but it doesn't return correct string. as below i tried with 'devesh' it gives 'hseesh'

```
var reverseString = function(s) {
    let j = 0
    for(let i=s.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        s[j++] = s[i]
    }
    return s
};

console.log(reverseString(['d', 'e', 'v', 'e', 's', 'h']))
// ['h', 's', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'd']`enter code here`
```

Comment: You are overwriting the string before it reaches the start with 
`s[j++] = s[i]`. You could create a new array and push the letters into the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because you're overwriting the `s` inside the `for` loop,

instead, create an empty one and fill it :

```js
var reverseString = function(s) {
  let j = 0;
  let newS = [];

  for (let i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    newS[j++] = s[i]
  }
  return newS;
};

console.log(reverseString(['d', 'e', 'v', 'e', 's', 'h']))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a much easier way to do this:

```
var reverseString = function(s) {
  return s.reverse();
};
```

Comment: well you are passing an array to the function so figure out which one you want.

Comment: I stand corrected. I did not realize an array was passed. (Also I'm not OP.)

Comment: Whoops, sorry I thought you were!

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid use the extra variable `j` and just push each letter into the result array, like so:

```js
const reverseString = values => {  
  const result = [];
  for(let i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    result.push(values[i]);
  }  
  return result;
};

console.log(reverseString(['a','b','c']))
```